# Terminology for Sockets: packet vs payload

Tags: java, sockets

This is a general question but I'm framing in the context of Java NIO non-blocking channel.

When receiving a payload over a channel it can arrive in multiple parts which must then be muxed together. Is the completed payload considered a "packet" or is that a term for the partial payload bits?

I'm not sure if the terms packet and payload are interchangeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What is sent over the wire is one or more IP packets.
2. These encapsulate IP headers and a TCP segment, possibly in a fragmented way.
3. This encapsulates TCP headers and an application payload, which you can consider as a byte-stream once all the packetization and segmentation and headers are stripped by the network layers.